# Failing test (testing-library/react): Unable to find an element with the text:

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-select, react-testing-library

I am trying to write some tests using testing-library/react of react-select (rc-select) component. The tests are now run, but the dropdown looks like this:
[image]

I'm also getting the warning in the console:
`react-dom.development.js:21 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key,` null`.`

What made the test run was changing from

````js
  <Option key={option.key || option} value={option.key || option}>
            {option.name || option}
          </Option>```
````

to

```js
 <Option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </Option>
```

**Code using testing-library/react:**

**SelectTestComponent:**

```js
import React from "react";
import Select from "../../packages/lab/src/select/Select.jsx";

const ReactSelectTestComponent = (props) => {
    const { options } = props;

    const onChange = (event) => {
        if (props.onChange) {
            props.onChange(event);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div data-testid="my-select-component">
            <Select
                className="basic-single"
                classNamePrefix="select"
                name="myOptions"
                placeholder="Select an option"
                options={options}
                onChange={onChange} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default ReactSelectTestComponent;
```

**Select.test.js:**

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import SelectTestComponent from "./SelectTestComponent";

it('should call onChange when the first option is selected', async () => {
  const mockedOptions = [
    { label: 'Mocked option 1', value: 'mocked-option-1' },
    { label: 'Mocked option 2', value: 'mocked-option-2' },
    { label: 'Mocked option 3', value: 'mocked-option-3' },
    { label: 'Mocked option 4', value: 'mocked-option-4' },
    { label: 'Mocked option 5', value: 'mocked-option-5' },
    { label: 'Mocked option 6', value: 'mocked-option-6' },
    { label: 'Mocked option 7', value: 'mocked-option-7' },
    { label: 'Mocked option 8', value: 'mocked-option-8' },
    { label: 'Mocked option 9', value: 'mocked-option-9' },
    { label: 'Mocked option 10', value: 'mocked-option-10' },
  ];

  const mockedOnChange = jest.fn();
  const { getByText, queryByTestId } = render(<SelectTestComponent
    options={mockedOptions}
    onChange={mockedOnChange} />);

  const mySelectComponent = queryByTestId('my-select-component');

  expect(mySelectComponent).toBeDefined();
  expect(mySelectComponent).not.toBeNull();
  // We trigger the right element to show autocomplete
  const input = mySelectComponent.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  fireEvent.keyDown(input, { key: 'ArrowDown' });

  // Leave as is
  await waitFor(() => getByText('Mocked option 1')[0]);
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Mocked option 1')[0]);

  expect(mockedOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  // Another change is to only selected value instead of entire option
  expect(mockedOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mocked-option-1');

})
```

**Error:**

**Select component:**

```js
/* eslint-disable react/forbid-prop-types */
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import styled from "styled-components";
import RcSelect, { Option } from "rc-select";
import { Icon } from "@opt-ui/core";
import { colors } from "@opt-ui/styles";
import { GlobalStyle } from "./Select.styles";

const ArrowContainer = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
`;

const BaseSelect = styled(RcSelect).attrs(() => { })`
  font-family: Equinor;
`;

// Component
const Select = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { className, options, value, menuItemSelectedIcon, ...other } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <BaseSelect
        ref={ref}
        className={className}
        value={value}
        inputIcon={
          <ArrowContainer>
            <Icon type="chevron_down" color={colors.grey20} />
          </ArrowContainer>
        }
        menuItemSelectedIcon={menuItemSelectedIcon}
        {...other}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <Option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
            {option.label}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </BaseSelect>
    </>
  );
});

Select.propTypes = {
  options: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.string, PropTypes.number]),
  menuItemSelectedIcon: PropTypes.element
};

Select.defaultProps = {
  value: undefined,
  menuItemSelectedIcon: null
};

export default Select;
```

Comment: What does your `<Select />` component look like?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I added the Select component now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked your code and found something you need to change to make it work properly.

Firstly, you might need to change your `Option` rendering only `label` and set value of an option is to literally set `value`:

```js
<Option key={option.value} value={option.value}> // key/value as unique key
  {option.label} // render only label
</Option>
```

Next thing is to trigger properly to show the autocomplete list by keydown to the `input` rendered by `rc-select`:

```js
// We trigger the right element to show autocomplete
const input = mySelectComponent.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
fireEvent.keyDown(input, { key: 'ArrowDown' });

// Leave as is
await waitForElement(() => getByText('Mocked option 1'));    
fireEvent.click(getByText('Mocked option 1'));

expect(mockedOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

// Another change is to only selected value instead of entire option
expect(mockedOnChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('mocked-option-1');
```

Comment: Thank you! Got the tests to run, however, the options in the dropwdown in the UI are now "invisible". Any idea on how to fix?

Comment: Autocomplete is appended to the body instead of a children elements that's why you can't see it as debug

Comment: I think you just should care you can click select the item which is the most important thing

Comment: One more thing, in case of you want to debug to see where the autocomplete is, you can log the document with: `console.log(prettyDOM(document));`

Comment: Thank you. That's a good tip. I updated the question now so you can see what I mean with invisible options in the UI.

Comment: Not sure if you implemented the right things but I made an example for you to test here https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-lichterman-ctxi4?file=/src/App.tsx